# I deleted admin user on Mac BigSur with sudo, can I acces files anyhow

Tags: macos, data-recovery, sudo, macos-bigsur

I deleted admin user on BigSur, the only user, with

```
sudo rm /var/db/.AppleSetupDone
```

and now can’t access my files. When turn on Mac, it asks me for language and else. I can access Terminal from Recovery. Why I did that - I followed https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/429700/cannot-upgrade-mac-osx-because-my-hard-drive-is-encrypted
But obviously did’t know what am I doing:(
Is there a way to restore or somehow replace that file?

Comment: It sounds like you didn't delete the user - just a file that serves as a marker of setup being done. Try to recreate the file with `touch /var/db/.AppleSetupDone`

Comment: I created new user and after logout from new one, I can login with old user. So data are all in place. I will backup first and then try to recreate it. Thanks

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164331/i-dont-have-administrator-account-on-my-mac

Comment: Touch said access denied (or similar) but everything is working and I don’t touch further. Your diagnosis helped. Thanks!